# Avoiding exposure to NullReferenceException when using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I am using a chain of calls to the `XElement.Element()` method to drill down into an XML document and pull out the value of an attribute:

```
XElement root = ...;
XNamespace ns = "...";
var firstName = 
  root
    .Element(ns + "Employee")
    .Element(ns + "Identity")
    .Element(ns + "Name")
    .Attribute(ns + "FirstName");
```

However, since the incoming document has not been schema validated it is possible that a malformed document will cause a `NullReferenceException` if any of the expected intermediate elements does not exist.

Is there a way to avoid this risk, whilst keeping the code succinct?

I can wrap the code above in a handler for `NullReferenceException` however this feels wrong, and would also not specifically indicate where the failure occurred. Constructing an informative error message would be manual, tedious, error prone, and a maintenance hazard.

Should I be using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) instead, that way I can check for a null return and then easily construct an error message indicating that the XPath expression could not be resolved?

Comment: Just to make sure, why isn't the incoming document validated?

Comment: Can you just use Descendents(ns + "FirstName") ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use `Elements()` instead of `Element()` - which will yield an empty sequence if the element isn't found. Using the extension methods in [Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.extensions.aspx), you can go from a sequence of elements *to* a sequence of elements - and the same for attributes. So:

```
var firstName = 
  root
    .Elements(ns + "Employee")
    .Elements(ns + "Identity")
    .Elements(ns + "Name")
    .Attributes(ns + "FirstName")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

There *is* a difference between the two snippets, mind you - this will find the first matching attribute even if it comes from (say) the first Name element within the third Identity element within the second Employee element. That may or may not be an issue for you.

(Just to check, do you definitely need the namespace on the attribute? Unlike elements, attributes don't inherit a "default" namespace. It's rarer to use attributes on namespaces than on elements.)

Comment: Excellent suggestion Jon. Now you just need a null check before you use the result, just as for an XPath evaluation. Out of interest, would you prefer to use this approach over an XPath expression? (And yes, in this case the schema I'm thinking of does indeed have namespaced attributes.)

Comment: @Daniel: Personally I'm not hugely fond of XPath within code - see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/code-and-data.aspx for my reasoning. Of course there are places where it makes sense, but in this case I'd probably go with the LINQ to XML solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can define en extension method to wrap the null detection. Something like this, for instance:

```
public static class XmlExtender
{
   public static XAttribute AttributeOrDefault(this XElement el, XName name, string defValue)
   {
      var v = el.Attribute(name);
      return v == null ? new XAttribute(name, defValue) : v;
   }

   public static string AttributeValue(this XElement el, XName name, string defValue)
   {
      var v = el.Attribute(name);
      return v == null ? defValue : v.Value;
   }
}
```

which can then be used like this:

```
var firstName = root.ELement("elname")
                    .AttributeOrDefault("attrName", "N/A").Value;
```

or this:

```
var firstName = root.Element("elname")
                    .AttributeValue("attrName", "N/A");
```